# Creating feature template in blank map of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, arcgis-10.3, template

I understand how to create features with existing templates, but sometimes a map has no templates to begin with and no layers to use to create them; perhaps just a basemap.

Is there a way within ArcMap to do this, or must I create features in Catalog first?

Answer (score 2):

In the ArcGIS for Desktop documentation the [About feature templates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/about-feature-templates.htm) page says (with my bolding):

> Creating features is accomplished through the use of feature
>   templates. Feature templates define all the information required to
>   create a feature: **the layer where a feature will be stored**, the
>   attributes a feature is created with, and the default tool used to
>   create that feature.

It is not possible to create a feature template until there is a layer in the map, and to create a layer it needs to have a data source.

Consequently, you need to first create a feature class in the Catalog window (or via the Create Feature Class tool), then add it to your map so that there is a layer with it as the source.  A feature template will then be automatically created if that layer is turned on when you start editing.